# Using st_intersects caused mismatch when a marking (tagging) shape marked a polygon overlapping only on the edge

Tags: postgis, intersection

I have accidentally marked a landshape as being tagged "CU GO-M" because it seems to share an *edge* with a tagshape for "CU GO-M" but nothing else. I used the st_intersects method to join these shapes erroneously. Which method should I use? This might be a dumb question because I think it is st_within, but I'm worried that might kick out some false negatives (rather than a false-positive, ie this case).

To summarize, I think any interior overlap match should be marked as tagged. This case marks the tagging for only an exterior (edge) intersect.

[image: 4816 Wendover has been tagged within this GO-M tagging district]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to check for an additional spatial relationship between geometries, [ST_Touches](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Touches.html).

Here's an example modified from the ST_Touches documentation:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 0 2)'::geometry, 'POINT(0 2)'::geometry) AS intersects,
       ST_Touches('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 0 2)'::geometry, 'POINT(0 2)'::geometry) AS touches,
       ST_Intersects('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 0 2)'::geometry, 'POINT(0 2)'::geometry) AND NOT ST_Touches('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 0 2)'::geometry, 'POINT(0 2)'::geometry) AS intersects_not_touches;
```

Which outputs:

```
intersects | touches | intersects_not_touches
----------------------------------------------
t          | t       | f
```

If you use the third column's example of `ST_Intersects() AND NOT ST_Touches()` then I think you will get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Arthur's theory & methods, I'm handling this situation in rails like so:

```
  BuncombeParcel.where{st_intersects(:thegeom, zoningblob)}.each do |p|
    next unless BuncombeParcel.where(:pin => p.pin).where{st_touches(:thegeom, zoningblob)}.blank? #there is only one parcel per pin
    #code to run for match
  end
```

I'm not very good with sql so this will work for now. Anyone who knows a more elegant way to do this using the squeel gem please let me know

NOTE: this strategy has caused some mismatches of a different type...ie I've got some parcels saying they're zoned according to an adjacent use. This might be projection transformation caused...investigating...